# RealVNC connection to VMware Workstation causes mouse to drift

Tags: windows-7, vnc, vmware-workstation

I am using RealVNC Viewer v4.4 to connect to a linux virtual machine in VMWare Workstation 6.5 installed on another computer.  The VMWare Workstation is configured to allow remote connections.  I am able to connect with RealVNC Viewer just fine.  However, my mouse moves to the lower right corner any time I move my mouse.  It is on a straight trajectory to the lower right corner no matter which direction I move my mouse.

It would seem that the Workstation is misinterpreting the mouse events.  I have played with many settings, reconnected, stopped and restarted the Workstation remote capabilities but I cannot fix the mouse drifting issue.